# 404 not resulted from post ajax call

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying to post some data to a web api controller but I seem to be getting back a 404 NOT Found response here is my code:

```
 public class CarsController : ApiController
{
  .....

    [HttpPost]
    public CarInputCharacteristicsDTO PostCharacteristics(CarInputCharacteristicsDTO characteristics)
    {
        return characteristics;
    } 
}

public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    }

  public class CarInputCharacteristicsDTO
{
    public int Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public int ModelType { get; set; }
    public int Fuel  { get; set; }
    public int Transmission { get; set; }
    public int BodyType { get; set; }
    public int PriceFrom { get; set; }
    public int PriceTo { get; set; }
    public int Power { get; set; }
    public int YearFrom { get; set; }
    public int YearTo { get; set; }
    public int KilometersFrom { get; set; }
    public int KilometersTo { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my Javascript code:

```
 display.on("click", function () {
    if (isValidInput()) {
        var data = {
            Manufacturer: manufacturer.val(),
            ModelType: modelType.val(),
            Fuel: fuel.val(),
            Transmission: transmision.val(),
            BodyType: bodyType.val(),
            PriceFrom: priceFrom.val(),
            PriceTo: priceTo.val(),
            Power: power.val(),
            YearFrom: yearFrom.val(),
            YearTo: yearTo.val(),
            KilometersFrom: kilometersFrom.val(),
            KilometersTo: kilometersTo.val()
        };
        var url = "http://localhost:3471/api/Cars/PostCharacteristics";

        $.post(url, JSON.stringify(data) , function(stuff) {
            console.log(stuff);
        });
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

This s the base path for my url :

[image]

The thing is I have also executed in another case a get request in the same way and it worked this is my code:

```
function getModelTypes(value) {
    var url = "http://localhost:3471/api/Cars/GetModelTypes/" + value;
    var modelTypeDefaultContent = "Please select a model";
    $.getJSON(url, function (arrayObjects) {
        ---
    });
}
```

If any other info is needed please let me know

Comment: Since I don't know what the IIS Express settings for your app are, I can't tell if the URL is incorrect or not, but I would recommend changing the URL defined in the AJAX call to a relative one "/api/Cars/PostCharacteristics" instead and let the client sort out the rest. That is the best information I can give at this time unless you are able to provide more details.

Comment: Do you see any other information in the body of the 404 response?...also could you share your Global.asax configuration...

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the code again, I realized you were missing the [FromBody] tag for the parameter for your method.

Try changing the code to as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public CarInputCharacteristicsDTO PostCharacteristics([FromBody]CarInputCharacteristicsDTO characteristics)
{
    return characteristics;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Using the code you have provided, it works correctly in a clean project. So there has to be some code elsewhere that is causing the issue. As Kiran has said, please provide the complete Global.asax file for further help in to this.

Comment: It's the same result I believe it has something to do with the routing....I am only able to call urls that have this format api/{controller}/{action}/{Id}